# The function strcpy doesn't work

Tags: c++, c

I had a homework saying that i should

> create a program which takes a string and remove all successive
>   repetitions in it.

i don't know why it doesn't work,
this is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch[50];
    gets(ch);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(ch)-1;i++);
    {
        while (ch[i] == ch[i+1])
            strcpy(ch+i,ch+i+1);
    }
    puts(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the output you are getting?

Comment: the input!
nothing changes really

Comment: `strcpy` can not be used to copy such content is duplicated. also `for (i=0;i<strlen(ch)-1;i++);` Last `;` it is superfluous.

Comment: how ? what should i do then ?

Comment: simple assignment(`=`) can solve this why are you using `strcpy`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It is not superfluous, but wrong.

Comment: ah it ok solved ! 
it worked by deleting the ; after for ! 
thanks man

Comment: The code is working perfectly fine. just remove the `;` after the `for`.

Comment: This code is still bad. The `C` and `C++` standards say if the `strcpy` source and destination overlap the behavior is undefined. Even if it works this code does an expensive string copy for each duplicate character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ; after for loop because it terminates the loop and is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
i was so blind ^^